# Giving wrong result with split_part in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using split_part in postgresql but getting the wrong result.

Details-

1) Resultvalue is Text datatype

2) normalrange is varchar datatype

3) If resultvalue is between the normalrange then it should give as 'Normal' and resultvalue is below Normalrange it should give me low else it should be High

## Sample Data

```
Result Value = 130
Normal Range = 97-137
```

---

See my code below

---

Code -

```
tppr.resultvalue "RESULT",
tppr.normalrange "RANGE",
case 
when tppr.resultvalue >= split_part(tppr.normalrange, '-', 1) and tppr.resultvalue <= split_part(tppr.normalrange, '-', 2) then 'NORMAL'
when tppr.resultvalue > split_part(tppr.normalrange, '-', 2) then 'High'
when tppr.resultvalue < split_part(tppr.normalrange, '-', 1) then 'Low' end as "Type",
```

---

I am getting the below result which is wrong-

```
|Result|Range |Type|
====================
|130   |97-137|Low |
--------------------
|5     |1-11  |High|
```

---

Comment: This is not answerable without seeing sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Please refer below sample data.

Result Value = 130 
Normal Range = 97-137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are comparing string values, so `5` > `11`, and `130` < `97`. `CAST` your values to `INT` (or `NUMERIC`/`FLOAT` if they can be floating point) and the problem is fixed:

```
select tppr.resultvalue "RESULT",
       tppr.normalrange "RANGE",
       case when cast(tppr.resultvalue as int) between cast(split_part(tppr.normalrange, '-', 1) as int) and cast(split_part(tppr.normalrange, '-', 2) as int) then 'NORMAL'
            when cast(tppr.resultvalue as int) > cast(split_part(tppr.normalrange, '-', 2) as int) then 'High'
            when cast(tppr.resultvalue as int) < cast(split_part(tppr.normalrange, '-', 1) as int) then 'Low' end as "Type"
from tppr
```

Output (for my sample data):

```
RESULT  RANGE   Type
130     97-137  NORMAL
90      97-137  Low
140     97-137  High
0       1-11    Low
5       1-11    NORMAL
12      1-11    High
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=627af429793cb7d139569da1d023e79b)

If `tppr.resultvalue` is of a numeric type already you won't need to `CAST` it.

Comment: Great!!!!! This worked if the values is in int format.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
I found some values in normalrange have text like -

No Risk: > 55 Moderate Risk: 35 - 55 High Risk: 0 - 35 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
I want this comparison to be excluded in above case when statement and in Normal/High/Low it should be blank

Comment: @jito you could add `WHERE tppr.normalrange ~ '\d+-\d+'` to only include rows with a valid range, or add `when tppr.normalrange !~ '\d+-\d+' then ''` to the beginning of the case to output a blank string in that scenario. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c4ba75d735c0a99d1ee1c5690ffee3c1